# how to do segmentation and feature extraction for this image?

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation, feature-extraction

I have problem with this image and I have more than one images like this. I got zeros value for this image. Can you teach or guide me on how to do segmentation and feature extraction on this image?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do feature extraction, I suggest you could look up at the matlabs builtin function for SURF(Speeded up robust features). Which would select interest points in the image and extract it based on what you need. Though I suggest that you should start learning on Neural Network since based on multiple researches, It is more accurate but nevertheless SURF answers your question regarding feature extraction

[image: Surf Descriptors]

https://www.mathworks.com/help/gpucoder/examples/feature-extraction-using-surf.html

IF for example you want to classify those images then i suggest you try to use BOVW (Bag-Of-Visual-Word).

https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/image-classification-with-bag-of-visual-words.html

Comment: I used sobel operator for the images but I don't have confident with the result I get.

Comment: The result comes down to what you want to get or what you want to show. Either way, I suggest that you try various feature extractors and compare each one to determine which one is more appropriate for your samples

Comment: Thank you.I will try it